# Adding a new SQL column with a default value

Tags: sql, mysql

I am looking for the syntax to add a column to a MySQL database with a default value of 0

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Answer (score 501, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN foo INT DEFAULT 0;
```

---

From the documentation that you linked to:

```
ALTER [ONLINE | OFFLINE] [IGNORE] TABLE tbl_name
   alter_specification [, alter_specification] ...

alter_specification:
    ...
    ADD [COLUMN] (col_name column_definition,...)
    ...
```

To find the syntax for `column_definition` search a bit further down the page:

> column_definition clauses use the same syntax for ADD and CHANGE as for CREATE TABLE. See [Section 12.1.17, “CREATE TABLE Syntax”.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

And from the linked page:

```
column_definition:  
   data_type [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT default_value]
   [AUTO_INCREMENT] [UNIQUE [KEY] | [PRIMARY] KEY]  
   [COMMENT 'string']  
   [COLUMN_FORMAT {FIXED|DYNAMIC|DEFAULT}]  
   [STORAGE {DISK|MEMORY|DEFAULT}]  
   [reference_definition]
```

Notice the word DEFAULT there.

Comment: I was particularly struck by how good this answer is, both concise and thorough, wish I could upvote it again

Comment: boolean and bool are synonyms for `TINYINT(1)` which is way more efficient than using `INT`, bear that in mind when using this "correct" answer

Comment: In case you need to add a boolean column with a default value of False, you can use: ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN foo boolean not null default 0;

Comment: "ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN foo INT DEFAULT 0;" - In this 'COLUMN' keyword is not required

Comment: Consider adding `NOT NULL`. Unless specified, a column with a default value can still be NULL, which often (but not always) defeats the purpose of the default value.

Answer (score 46):

Like this?

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD `new_col_name` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

Comment: if default is >0, add quotes: ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD `new_col_name` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT  '1';

Answer (score 7):

table users (user_id int unsigned PK, username varchar(32))

```
alter table users add column verified tinyint unsigned default 0
```

Answer (score 7):

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN new_field TinyInt(1) DEFAULT 0;
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why did you need to add a new answer to this question?

Answer (score 5):

Simply add `default 0` at the end of your `ALTER TABLE <table> ADD COLUMN <column> <type>` statement

Answer (score 4):

This will work for ENUM type as default value

```
ALTER TABLE engagete_st.holidays add column `STATUS` ENUM('A', 'D') default 'A' AFTER `H_TYPE`;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this,

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name INT DEFAULT 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Another useful keyword is FIRST and AFTER if you want to add it in a specific spot in your table.

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD COLUMN `foo` AFTER `bar` INT DEFAULT 0;
```

Comment: AFTER `bar` should be *after INT

Answer (score 2):

If you are learning it's helpful to use a GUI like [SQLyog](https://github.com/webyog/sqlyog-community), make the changes using the program and then see the History tab for the DDL statements that made those changes.

Answer (score 1):

> **Try This :)**

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN_NAME INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```