# ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT gets Error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, alter-table

The tables User and Properties were created properly.

```
CREATE TABLE Properties
(
    ID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    language int,
    stonecolor int,
    gamefield int,
    UserID int,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(language) REFERENCES Language(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(stonecolor) REFERENCES StoneColor(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(gamefield) REFERENCES GameField(ID)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE User
(
    ID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    vorname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    nickname varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    score int,
    isadmin int DEFAULT 0,
    gamesPlayed int,
    properties int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    UNIQUE (email),
    UNIQUE (nickname)

) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

But `ALTER TABLE User` doesn't work.

```
ALTER TABLE User 
(
    ADD CONSTRAINT userPropertie
    FOREIGN KEY(properties)
    REFERENCES Properties(ID)
)
```

Can't figure out why?

I used this as a reference: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

> Error 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
> ADD CONSTRAINT userPropertie
> FOREIGN KEY(properties)
> REFERENCES Properties(' at line 2

Comment: FYI: [adding a new sql column with a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569347/) or [adding multiple columns after a specific column in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541312/) or [add a column to mysql table if it does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972922/)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Omit the parenthesis:

```
ALTER TABLE User 
    ADD CONSTRAINT userProperties
    FOREIGN KEY(properties)
    REFERENCES Properties(ID)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER TABLE `User`
ADD CONSTRAINT `user_properties_foreign`
FOREIGN KEY (`properties`)
REFERENCES `Properties` (`ID`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table User 
    add constraint userProperties
    foreign key (properties)
    references Properties(ID)
```

Comment: Please try to add an explanation of how this code solves the question