# adding another to column and fill it with values

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

I have a full working table. it already has data. I need to put another column that will serve as a serial code of each row that was created. the format of the serial code would be user-1, user-2, etc. how do I do that?

Comment: u can do that by `what have you tried?`

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569347/adding-a-new-sql-column-with-a-default-value