# Alter table add column and set default value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ddl

Is there a way to add a new column and set its default value in MySQL? When I run this command I get a syntax error:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD newColumn varchar(20) SET DEFAULT 'test';
```

The documentation I've found doesn't really help me.

Comment: Thanks, it works now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a new SQL column with a default value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569347/adding-a-new-sql-column-with-a-default-value)

Answer (score 7):

The `SET` shouldn't be necessary:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD newColumn varchar(20) DEFAULT 'test';
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

ALTER TABLE tableName ADD COLUMN newColumn VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'test';