# What is the equivalent of "DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR" in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have some data from Sql Server and I want to create the same data in Mysql but I have an error.
This is the syntax from Sql server:

```
ALTER TABLE [SecurityServices].[acces_grp_usr] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_ACCES_GRP_USR_ID_CALQ]  DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR [ID_CALQ]
```

I changed it like this in mysql:

```
ALTER TABLE acces_grp_usr ADD  CONSTRAINT DF_ACCES_GRP_USR_ID_CALQ  DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR ID_CALQ
```

and this is the error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR ID_CALQ' at line 1

thanks for your help.

Comment: Um, you can't use SQL Server syntax in MySQL. Why did you think this would work?

Comment: I changed it in mysql and it didn't work I just posted it like this so you can understand what I'm talking about

Comment: That error message indicates that you didn't change the syntax at all. You should post what you are actually trying to run in MySQL if you want to get any help.

Comment: I changed it thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a new SQL column with a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569347/adding-a-new-sql-column-with-a-default-value)

Comment: I found the answer in case someone has the same error : ALTER TABLE acces_grp_usr MODIFY id_calq INT DEFAULT -1